# How to put string elements separated by commas into an int array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

This is the example:5,6,13,4,14,22, .
 I want to fill the array with 5 6 13 4 12 22
After compilation it returns : 5 6 , 3 4 , 4 , 2 .
When I introduce 2,3,5,1,6,4 the array will be the correct one.

```
int nr=0;
    for(int j=0;j<sizeOfString;j++){
        if ((string[j] == ',')){
            output << j <<" j  ";//comma positions
        }else{
            stringArrayg[nr++]= putchar(string[j-2]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: While [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) is commonly used to read "lines", it also have an argument that lets users of it specify the "line ending". Together with e.g. an [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) it can be used to tokenize strings containing any field separator (like e.g. the comma). Then it's just a matter of [converting the strings to `int` values](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

Comment: I wanted to keep comma as separator when I will fill the array.But if I read the string char by char, how can I store the two ciphers between commas as in my example?

Comment: How you declare `stringArrayg`?

Comment: Please decide what you want, an int array as the title says or a string array as implied elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that uses vectors, std::replace, and std::istringstream:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> convertToIntArray(std::string input)
{
    std::replace(input.begin(), input.end(), ',', ' ');

    std::istringstream stringReader{ input };

    std::vector<int> result;

    int number;
    while (stringReader >> number)
    {
        result.push_back(number);
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::string testString = "5,6,13,4,14,22";

    std::vector<int> newArray = convertToIntArray(testString);

    for (int i = 0; i < newArray.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << newArray[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using [Boost::Tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/tokenizer/) as like that:

```
include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
int main()
{
    string str = "5,6,13,4,14,22"; /// string to parse
    vector<int> nums; /// vector containing the numbers extracted from the string


    char_separator<char> sep(","); /// char separator for the tokenizer
    /// extracting all the tokens separated by ","
    tokenizer<char_separator<char> > tokens(str, sep); 

    /// looping over the tokes and storing them in the vector by
    /// casting each token to an int
    std::transform( tokens.begin(), tokens.end(), std::back_inserter(nums), &boost::lexical_cast<int,std::string> );

    /// printing the vector content
    for(const auto &v: nums) {
        cout << v << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```